# Markdown Paragraph

Tags: formatting, markdown, paragraph

I'm encountering a problem in Markdown paragraph.

I use Notepad in Microsoft Windows to create .md file and use Typora for rendering.

The new lines in the same paragraph are treated as new line in rendering.

For example, if my .md file contains the following text

```
Electric Field inside
a conductor
is zero
```

The Typora renders as it is with new lines....whereas it is expected the rendering should be like this

```
Electric Field inside a conductor is zero.
```

i.e new lines inside the same paragraph to be formatted in proper paragraph sense and not like code listing.  Whats the mistake I' doing ?.

Answer (score 0):

Typora seems to not follow typical Markdown behavior in this regard. As explained in their [documentation](http://support.typora.io/Markdown-Reference/#paragraph-and-line-breaks):

> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text. In
> markdown source code, paragraphs are separated by two or more blank
> lines. In Typora, you only need one blank line (press `Return` once)
> to create a new paragraph.
>
> Press `Shift + Return` to create a single line break. Most other
> markdown parsers will ignore single line breaks, so in order to make
> other markdown parsers recognize your line break, you can leave two
> spaces at the end of the line, or insert `<br/>`.

Comment: Thats nice!  thanks for your answer. I tried MarkdownPad2 and also ``markdown`` utility in Linux.. it works fine...